# Matplotlib: Need Co-ordinates of points of drawn surfaceplot or intersection of rstrides and cstrides of wireframe plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, wireframe

Matplotlib: I have an array of points in 3d and using matplotlib to plot wireframe plot and surface plot. After plotting surface plot or wireframe plot I wanted co-ordinates of all points drawn on a surface plot in 3D. I searched a lot, looked into the documentation as well but was not able to find anything. Either point on surface plot or coordinates of all intersection of rstrides and cstrides of wireframe will also do.
I kind of provide points which are plotted in scatterplot. When I plot wireframe matplotlib plots grid like structure on top of it. I want coordinates of where the horizontal and vertical lines intersects on wireframe or any random points on colored surface in surface plot other than the points provided by me.
PS-  not allowed to add images as less than 10 reps

Comment: You supply the coordinates of the surface of wireframe plot yourself via the arguments `x` and `y`  of `plot_surface(x,y,z)`. There should not be any need to obtain them from the plot because you already have them even without any plot. But maybe you are asking for something else? In that case consider that the question does not allow to find out what that would be.

Comment: We provide only X,Y,Z coordinates to plot points on the plot, surface is drawn by matplotlib. I want coordinates of points on that surface drawn by matplotlib expect points provided by me.

Comment: Taking [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html), there are no points. And there is nothing in the plot that hasn't been provided via code to it. So if your case is different, show your case and explain what you need to find out.